# yii renderPartial view contain two blank lines

Tags: php, yii

I try to modify someone yii framework project, when i renderPartial

```
$this->renderPartial('view');
```

in the view.php

```
<?php
echo 'phase1';
?>
```

in the browse it shows phase1 in the first line

[image]

but in the view source code
it starts with two blank lines

[image]

I don't know where those blank lines come from, and how to delete those lines.

Comment: Try to clear output buffer before `$this->renderPartial('view');`. If that helps - search used `php` files for blank lines before `<?php` or after `?>`

Comment: I don't uderstand your goal, do you want pase1 is showed two line below the navbar?

Comment: @scaisEdge I don't want to showed two lines, but want to find why it showed two lines in the page source code

Comment: @ineersa it works, thanks, but why clear output buffer can delete the blank lines

Comment: @AntiGMO it means that somewhere in your php files you have blank lines before `<?php` or after closing tag. Search used files. I've spend half of day fixing my `json` response with similar issue.

Comment: @ineersa, add your solution as an answer please. I almost missed that this was a solution to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

"in the browse it shows phase1 in the first line, but in the source code it starts with two blank lines" - did you mean the opposite?

Most PHP frameworks including Yii uses theme concept for rendering web pages. Take a look at [Yii docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming). So, the empty lines shown at start of the webpage might be coming from the header file which can be found under `WebRoot > themes > [theme-name] > views > layouts`. Take a look at the header/layout file; you may find your "two empty lines" there.

Comment: Thanks, i update the post. but i use the renderPartial, it will not use the layouts

Comment: That shouldn't be a real problem. It might be coming from the previously rendered file. Check that too. Also, I think this question should be closed.

Comment: previously rendered file?? this action only renderPartial one view, and the controller extends Controller

Comment: so you are saying that this is the first file you are rendering, and you are using renderPartial, right? In that case check the `index.php` or `config/main.php` files for possible "empty lines". Also, this seems impossible for SO users to debug as this can be caused because of a typo in the code and sharing/debugging the whole project seems to be an exhaustive process.

Comment: @dreamster This is actually a really good question, idk why you want to close it. When I had similar issue I found no answer and debugged all project as you said.

Comment: @ineersa I think this is a user specific issue and can't really see how this is an important one, but I can be wrong.